# Dual monitor setup through USB-C - both monitors detected, only one displaying at a time

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display

I have an Asus Rog Strix G15 laptop and I use a docking station connected via USB-C with 2 HDMI ports (UtechSmart), to which I connect 2 external monitors, respectively. I have Windows as second boot, and it manages to display on both external monitors.

Until recently, displaying on both external monitors worked on Ubuntu as well. However it doesn't work now. Both external monitors are detected in the settings, however, when I toggle on both, only one of them actually works. I can switch on any of the 2 external monitors through Display Settings, but not both.

Did anybody encounter and/or solved this issue?

```
$ inxi --basic
System:    Host: eugen-ROG-Strix-G512LV-G512LV Kernel: 5.15.0-43-generic x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: Gnome 3.36.9 
           Distro: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS (Focal Fossa) 
Machine:   Type: Laptop System: ASUSTeK product: ROG Strix G512LV_G512LV v: 1.0 serial: <superuser/root required> 
           Mobo: ASUSTeK model: G512LV v: 1.0 serial: <superuser/root required> UEFI: American Megatrends v: G512LV.310 
           date: 07/13/2020 
Battery:   ID-1: BAT0 charge: 54.8 Wh condition: 54.8/66.0 Wh (83%) 
CPU:       8-Core: Intel Core i7-10870H type: MT MCP speed: 3195 MHz min/max: 800/5000 MHz 
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel UHD Graphics driver: i915 v: kernel 
           Device-2: NVIDIA TU106 [GeForce RTX 2060] driver: nouveau v: kernel 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.13 driver: modesetting,nvidia unloaded: fbdev,nouveau,vesa 
           resolution: 1920x1080~144Hz, 1920x1080~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel UHD Graphics (CML GT2) v: 4.6 Mesa 21.2.6
```

Thanks

Comment: You mention the issue occurred only recently; 20.04 has it's 20.04.5 changes rolling out now, ie. you've only recently switched from the 5.13 kernel to 5.15 (*which comes with 20.04.5*) and as kernel modules (aka *drivers*) are linked to kernel, one option maybe using the GA kernel stack by default (ie. use 5.4 which is supported the life of 20.04).  This may not be the best option, but it maybe one fallback (*if using open source, both kernel stacks can co-exist allowing for exploration of other fixes too with 5.15, but some closed source kernel modules prevent multiple stacks co-existing*)

Comment: @guiverc - thanks for the comment. I tried downgrading the kernel:
- 5.13 - didn't help, same issue as currently
- 5.4 - output actually goes to both monitors, but not functional - for one of the monitors is frozen.